Shining in Daniel 12:3
Several years ago I heard in a sermon (from John MacArthur I think) that, corresponding to Daniel 12:3 where it says those who have insight will shine like stars, that our ultimate reward in heaven will be the capacity to radiate the glory of God in all eternity. It was something like that. I have heard the teaching two other times, perhaps from preachers who got it from MacArthur or his source. This idea has captivated me for quite a few years.
Can any of you help me find more information on this topic and possibly help in understanding whether this is a valid idea? Thank you.

In Judaism, the light of creation on the first day is said to be the soul of the Messiah.

I've never heard any of his sermons but have 2 of his books. The indexes did not help find links to the topic or the Daniel verse you ask about. In one 1988 book where he taught "Incarnational sonship", a note I scribbled says: "He has now recanted that". The best thing might be to ask a fresh Q in Hermeneutics, asking what the meaning of Daniel 12:3 is in context of a terrible time of trouble, names written in a book, the resurrection, and "they that turn many to righteousness as the stars for ever and ever." I've noted Hosea 14:9 as linked to Daniel 12:3.

I'm going to propose an in-depth study of the text of Daniel 12:3.
Biblical text
Daniel 12:3 (LSG) : "Those who have been clever will shine like the splendor of the sky, and those who have taught righteousness to the many will shine like the stars, forever and ever."
Etymological analysis
Key words:
Intelligent (Hebrew: מַשְׂכִּילִים, maskilim)
Root: שׂכַל (sakal), meaning "to have discernment, to be wise, to understand". Here, the term refers to those with enlightened spiritual understanding.
Connotation: wisdom that leads to enlightened action.
Will shine (Hebrew: יָזִהִירוּ, yaz'hiru)
Root: זהר (zahar), meaning "to shine, to be resplendent". The word is often associated with divine light and dazzling glory.
Justice (Hebrew: צְדָקָה, tsedaqah)
Root: צדק (tsedeq), meaning "justice, righteousness, equity". This can refer to moral righteousness or a right relationship with God.
Stars (Hebrew: כּוֹכָבִים, kokhavim)
Used here metaphorically to denote eternal, divine glory.
Exegetical analysis
Immediate context:
Daniel 12 belongs to an eschatological vision given to Daniel concerning the end times.
The preceding verses (Daniel 12:1-2) speak of a period of great distress, followed by the resurrection of the dead (to eternal life or eternal shame). Daniel 12:3 emphasizes the reward of the righteous.
Meaning of verse:
The intelligent represent those who possess divine knowledge and act with discernment. They are distinguished by their role in teaching and propagating divine justice.
The image of the stars evokes eternal glory and a luminous presence in the celestial sphere, underlining immortality and divine reward.
Textual criticism
The Massoretic text of Daniel 12:3 is well preserved, with few variants.
The Septuagint (LXX) manuscripts translate maskilim as οἱ συνιῶντες (those who understand), reinforcing the idea of spiritual wisdom.
The Qumran manuscripts (e.g. 4QDana) confirm the stability of the Hebrew text.
Hermeneutical analysis
Main themes :
Wisdom and spiritual intelligence: The verse exalts those who act with discernment and spiritual understanding.
Teaching righteousness: The active role of leading others to a right relationship with God.
Eternal reward: The comparison with the stars emphasizes the idea of glory and immortality.
Applications:
This passage calls believers to live as shining witnesses and to teach righteousness.
Hermeneutically, it anticipates New Testament themes of light and witness (cf. Matthew 5:14-16).
Highlights
Duality between understanding and action: True wisdom is demonstrated through teaching and practice.
Eschatological dimension: This text links earthly efforts with an eternal heavenly reward.
Metaphor of the stars: Underlining the permanence and glory of the righteous in eternity.
Theological conclusion
Theology of light: Light is a central symbol representing divine revelation and the glory promised to those who follow God.
Mission of believers: Those who teach and live righteousness reflect God's character and plan for humanity.
Eschatological hope: The passage nurtures a vision of resurrection and eternal life, where the faithful will enjoy incomparable glory.
References
Biblical references:
Proverbs 11:30: "The fruit of the righteous is a tree of life, and the wise man takes souls."
Matthew 5:14-16: "You are the light of the world."
Philippians 2:15: "You shine like torches in the world."
Historical evidence:
The Qumran manuscripts confirm the authenticity of the text.
Contemporary Jewish apocalyptic writings (such as 1 Enoch) emphasize similar themes of eternal glory.
Secondary studies :
Baldwin, Joyce G. Daniel: An Introduction and Commentary.
Collins, John J. Daniel: A Commentary on the Book of Daniel.
In conclusion, I would be sure to say that this text offers a powerful call to believers to reflect divine light and actively participate in God's plan to bring justice to the world.
What do you think?
Happy holidays to all under the Lord's blessings and grace.

An interesting and helpful answer. Could you advise me what Bible is L.S.G? (I have problems with abbreviations!)

This is the Bible version Louis Second

Thank you! A very thorough answer.

Jeremie, in your answer minutes ago on a Hermeneutic Q re. Rev 22:21 saying ‘Amen’, you indicate a translation of the KJV by Louis Segond 1910. Or did you mean, Louis Segon who died 1910?

Here's what I said:
Some versions include "Amen" (Segond, KJV), marking a liturgical or solemn ending.
That is: (Segond and KJV).

Christians are called to let their light shine in the darkness, so there is an earthly precedent for this heavenly vision.  Especially at this time of the year we focus on how Christ Jesus is the light and life of the world:

The light shines in the darkness, but the darkness has not understood it (John 1:5).


In Matthew 5:16, Jesus says, “Let your light shine before others, so that they may see your good works and give glory to your Father who is in heaven.” Of course, it is not technically our light that should shine before others. It is the light of Christ, entrusted to believers as light-bearers (cf. John 1:8). In other words, we do not produce the light within us. God does. And through our good works, people may glorify the One who gives that light.

Here are some practical ways we are encouraged to do that now:

Practice humility (Philippians 2:1–11).


Show compassion (Matthew 9:36; 15:32; Mark 6:34).


Be generous with our money, time, resources, and love (Romans 12:13; Hebrews 13:16).


Forgive others as we have been forgiven (Matthew 18:15–20; cf. Ephesians 4:32).


Share the gospel, the “good news,” with others.


The ultimate purpose of letting our light shine before others is not to draw attention to ourselves or to promote our own interests; rather, it is about living in such a way that others will glorify our Father in heaven.
Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/let-your-light-shine.html

We might as well start practicing now, here on earth, before we reach our eternal destination where we shall constantly praise and worship the creator of light and life.
I realise this might not be quite what you had in mind when you posted this question, but it might be a useful starting point for our thoughts?

Thank you. A lot of useful things to consider here.
